# How can I fetch distinct keys from table in parse DB?

Tags: php, parse-platform

I want to fetch distinct values of a particular column using REST APIs. But I am not getting any way to perform this action.

Has anybody got any solution to it? Please share it here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean not duplicated data?

Comment: You would need to do this on the client.  Parse does not have a distinct query method.

Comment: Yes. I need unique data just like results of sql query "SELECT DISTINCT column_name
FROM table_name;"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Distinct query method is not seen in parse. So you need to use array_unique() in php, so that you will get only unique values.
Here is a sample code

```
            <?php
                    $uid=$somevalue;
                    $query = new ParseQuery("user_class");
                    $query->equalTo("userid",$uid);
                    $results = $query->find();
                    for ($k = 0; $k < count($results); $k++)
                    {
                        $object = $results[$k];
                        $uname[] = $object->get('username');
                        $unq_dt=array_values(array_unique($uname));
                    }

                    foreach($unq_dt as $key=>$dt_val)
                    {
                        echo $dt_val;
                    }
              ?>
```

array_unique() is used to get unique values and array_values() is used to reset the array key.